# Java Thread doesn't live as long as the main program does

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-commons

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to instantiate via Apache Commons Exec an instance of a second .jar apart from the main one which throws this second Java program.

What this second .jar does is basically send bytes to the stdout. This is the code that launches this program.

```
private void runJar(PipedOutputStream output) throws IOException {
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();

    CommandLine commandLine;
    String executeMe = "java -jar myjar.jar";
    commandLine = CommandLine.parse(executeMe);

    executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(output, null));
    executor.execute(commandLine, new DefaultExecuteResultHandler());
}
```

But so far I couldn't find a way to execute this without blocking the normal flow of the normal program with the library, so what I did as a workaround is to create  Thread, like this...

```
Thread t3 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            runJar(output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
t3.start();
```

I've tried launching the commands via the cmd and everything works properly, but in this case when I run everything inside Java the Thread seems to stop after several seconds.

Am I missing something when I create a new Thread so it can live as long as the main program does?

**UPDATE:**

A runnable example from the first .jar can be this code...

```
public class SecondApp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {
            File in = new File(args[0]);
    try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(in)) {
        int bytesRead, CHUNK_SIZE = 4096;
        byte[] data = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];

        while (true) {
            bytesRead = input.read(data, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
                            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                                System.out.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
                                System.out.flush();
                            } else if (bytesRead == -1) {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
        }

    }
}
```

It basically spits out bytes to the `stdout`. The third app is just an external one (ffmpeg), which receives those bytes from this second .jar via a PipedInputStream, like this...

```
PipedOutputStream output = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream input = new PipedInputStream();
output.connect(input);
```

In order to debug and know the Thread status succesfully, I've changed the asynchronous execution for a synchronous one, and now I get that both threads are in RUNNABLE state and are ALIVE.

```
@Override
public void run() {
        try {
            DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();

            CommandLine commandLine;
            String executeMe = "java -jar myjar.jar";
            commandLine = CommandLine.parse(executeMe);

            executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(output, null));
            executor.execute(commandLine); //, new DefaultExecuteResultHandler());
        } catch (ExecuteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

As @matt stated, it may be a problem of the output from the FFMPEG thread not being consumed.

```
            executor.setStreamHandler(
                new PumpStreamHandler(
                        null, // stdout
                        null, // stderr
                        input)); // stdin
```

That was the previous line from the FFMPEG executor, now changed by a NullOutputStream (the one from Apache Commons Exec).

```
            executor.setStreamHandler(
                new PumpStreamHandler(
                        new NullOutputStream(), // stdout
                        null, // stder
                        input)); // stdin
```

After those changes, the stream seems to stop after few seconds, so it may be the reason @matt said, the stream isn't being consumed and gets full. Why isn't it working with a NullOutputStream()?

Comment: You need to consume the std out otherwise the std out will block the other process. You might want to consider zt exec.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like the t3 run method is finishing, What is runStreamer, and why should it block?

Comment: @matt Forgot to modify the t3 code for the example, sorry for that. runJar basically spits bytes through the stdout, and a thirt process (ffmpeg) receives them to stream those bytes to Icecast. Both should just run until the processes are killed or the application terminated.

Comment: What do you mean the "thread stops"? Did you check if runJar is finishing?

Comment: Can you generalize the exception in the t3 thread or catch an InterruptedException as well as the IOException?

Comment: @matt @Michael McKay I mean that when I log into the Icecast control panel the stream is active for several seconds, and suddenly it stops. Both threads doesn't throw any exception, even after generalizing them.

I ran runJar and ffmpeg via the cmd, using the pipe operator to feed ffmpeg with the output from runJar and it works flawlessly. Maybe it's because ffmpeg doesn't have any PipedOutputStream to send the output to?

`executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(null, null, input));`

Comment: You haven't really provided something that is reproducible. The executable in `runJar` is absolutely unknown to us, maybe make a dummy that does similar. You also haven't made it clear, is your thread terminating or just blocking? You need to make sure the output from run jar execution is being consumed. Maybe provide some evidence of that. What, in the method of runJar, blocks to prevent the method from finishing. I think you need a different executor service.

Comment: @matt Sorry for the delay as I'm quite busy. I've added more details about the problem and my first failed approach to solve it.